# Raid0 disappeared after ubuntu upgrade. How to recover it?

Tags: data-recovery, raid

I may need a lot of help here..
After upgrading ubuntu from 16.04 ->18.04 ->20.04, my raid0 array disappeared. I wish to reassemble the raid array. While working on this, I might have committed a critical mistake (please see below).

Initially, I checked the hard drives and partitions. `sudo fdisk -l`

```
...
...

Disk /dev/sdc: 1.88 TiB, 2048408248320 bytes, 4000797360 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 850 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 1.88 TiB, 2048408248320 bytes, 4000797360 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 850 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1           1 4294967295 4294967295   2T ee GPT


Disk /dev/sdd: 1.88 TiB, 2048408248320 bytes, 4000797360 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 850 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdb: 1.88 TiB, 2048408248320 bytes, 4000797360 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 850 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
...
...
```

`lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,FSTYPE,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT`

```
NAME     SIZE FSTYPE            TYPE MOUNTPOINT
...
...
sda      1.9T linux_raid_member disk 
sdb      1.9T linux_raid_member disk 
sdc      1.9T linux_raid_member disk 
sdd      1.9T linux_raid_member disk 
...
...
```

After reading some blog posts, I tried to re-assemble my raid0 array using this commend: `sudo mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=0 --raid-devices=4 /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd` Unfortunately, I may have made a critical mistake here..

```
mdadm: chunk size defaults to 512K
mdadm: /dev/sda appears to be part of a raid array:
       level=raid0 devices=4 ctime=Sat Mar 26 11:25:34 2022
mdadm: partition table exists on /dev/sda but will be lost or
       meaningless after creating array
mdadm: /dev/sdb appears to be part of a raid array:
       level=raid0 devices=4 ctime=Sat Mar 26 11:25:34 2022
mdadm: /dev/sdc appears to be part of a raid array:
       level=raid0 devices=4 ctime=Sat Mar 26 11:25:34 2022
mdadm: /dev/sdd appears to be part of a raid array:
       level=raid0 devices=4 ctime=Sat Mar 26 11:25:34 2022
Continue creating array?
```

Here, I said "y".

Then, I felt something wrong; because even though I see `md0` in `lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,FSTYPE,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT`, it looks like it needs a format.
Then, I ran `mdadm --stop /dev/md0`.

( By the way, I obtained all messages above after I made mistake. So, the message might be slightly different. In the case of `fdisk -l`, the partition order might be different. In the `mdadm --create`, the warning message might be "partition table exists on /dev/sda1`..."; but I am not 100% sure. :( )

I would really like to recover my raid0 array. Could anyone guide me?

**--------------------Update_001--------------------**

1. It turned out that the server had dual booting. Somehow, it has not been working anymore, and the GRUB did not show any Windows booting option. This may explain the GPT format shown in `fdisk -l`.
2. RAID could be set-up in BIOS. The company, from which we purchased the system, guided me to re-build RAID from BIOS. This may be the reason why it is possible to have a "windows" partition in one of the raid hard drives.
3. Unfortunately, it did not restore the data. While I see /dev/md127, it dose seem to require format. Would it be possible that this is happening because I created a new RAID with `mdadm --create`, and it automatically re-build the raid at boot while ignoring the raid from BIOS?

The below is what I executed BEFORE setting the RAID in BIOS:

```
sudo mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=0 --raid-devices=4 /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd
```

#I also tried /dev/md127 instead of /dev/md0; but if my memory is correct, md0 became md127 by itself after rebooting. Yet, maybe I am wrong.

```
sudo mdadm --detail --scan | sudo tee -a /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf update-initramfs
```

Also, there is `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` file, just in case it is helpful..

```
# mdadm.conf
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
# wildcards if desired.
#DEVICE partitions containers

# auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays
ARRAY metadata=imsm UUID=187206c9:7332f2e4:fffa5ab4:7e0e39b8
ARRAY /dev/md/RAID0 container=187206c9:7332f2e4:fffa5ab4:7e0e39b8 member=0 UUID=a3d9b7b2:6ebe6085:da76722e:c157c5da

# This file was auto-generated on Tue, 15 Nov 2016 20:06:03 -0500
# by mkconf $Id$
ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=1.2 name=friedman-idisco:0 UUID=ab32f8a0:75049fe2:5a9fce77:246bdf00
```

The company guy couldn't figure out; but mentioned Intel RSTe publication which mentions using MDRAID.
Would anyone see possibility of restoring the data?
Disabling mdadm would restore the original setup (which i don't know how to)?

Comment: It could have been raid linear. Omg, I have not so much information. Are there any way to check the previous setup?

Comment: Do not know RAID, but your sda says type is DOS, but has one partition table entry that says gpt. That is typically for gpt partitioned drives. None of your other drives show MBR nor gpt. Typically RAID 0 not recommended unless you have really good backups. Don't bother with RAID 0 unless you have a specific need for speed without data redundancy, since if one drive goes out, you lose the whole array.
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2444499

Comment: Yes, this was puzzling to me. However, because I do not know much about partitions, I did not pay attention to it. This array was created by someone else before me; and I wasn't aware of linear raid until today. Now, I think it was probably "linear"; because I did not see any reason to use raid0 for this server.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I see:

You dont't seem to be expecting these devices to have partitions, but one (sda) does. The type of this partition is `0xee`, which seems to be `Microsoft GPT protective MBR`. Where does this partition come from? Is this a Dual-Boot setup with Windows beside Ubuntu? Could a Windows update have created this? Was it a remainder from an earlier Windows installation that maybe didn't trip the Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 kernels, but threw the Ubuntu 20.04 kernel off guard?

Re-creating the array with `mdadm --create` was not a good idea. It reported `appears to be part of a raid array` for all four devices, so the mdadm superblocks were still left and from what is visible seem to have been correct (all say `level=raid0 devices=4 ctime=Sat Mar 26 11:25:34 2022`). You would probably have been able to recover the RAID with `mdadm --examine`, `mdadm --assemble` and the likes.

Instead you overwrote the old superblocks, and if you can't see the original file system now, it probably means the new RAID has most likely been created with the devices in a different order than the old RIAD, or uses a different chunk size, or a different alignments, or something else. If you don't have a backup of the old superblocks and don't known the old settings, you can try different settings for `mdadm create`, but I would suggest you start looking for your backups.

I would also strongly suggest to switch from an mdadm RAID0 to ZFS RAIDZ1 or RAIDZ2. Normal software RAID is severely outdated in many regards.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have no idea why there is GPT partition. This is a shared server and someone before me might have done something. For " you can try different settings for mdadm create", would you mean I could try something like  "mdadm --create level = linear"?

Comment: What I meant was options like `--chunk=`, `--bitmap-chunk=` and changing the order of the drives. `--level=linear` could also be a possibility, didn't think of that since I've never seen it being used.

But it is hard to say if it is even possible to recreate the old layout.

Comment: Okay, it sounds quite complicating... Is there a way to use superblock backups? `mke2fs -n /dev/sda/` resulted in `Creating filesystem with 500099670 4k blocks and 125026304 inodes
Filesystem UUID: c07d14df-527b-4ce0-bc7d-d2d8221b1df9
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
 32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
 4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968, 
 102400000, 214990848`

Comment: I got some progress (?) and updated my post. Would you have any thought?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem installing 22.04 from 32bit 18.04
I fixed the problem reading the doc of `dmraid`

Try:

```
sudo dmraid -ay
```

In fact your disks are deactivate after the install,
applying the `-ay` reactive them.

You  can remount the raid with common command like

```
sudo mount /dev/mapper/isw_hjcgfdcf_Volume2p1 /media/backup/
```

But normally, system should mount them automatically.

Hope it help others

kindly
sharktrade